# Parsing JSON inside XML response php

Tags: php, xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:getRatesResponse xmlns:ns1="urn:rpxwsdl">
            <return xsi:type="xsd:string">{&quot;RPX&quot;:{&quot;TITLE&quot;:&quot;Rates From Jakarta (JAK) TO Denpasar (DPS), Weight 1 Kg&quot;,&quot;DATA&quot;:[{&quot;SERVICE&quot;:&quot;PAS Reguler (PSR)&quot;,&quot;FREIGHT_CHARGE&quot;:&quot;27723&quot;,&quot;TOT_CHARGE&quot;:&quot;27723&quot;,&quot;PRICE&quot;:&quot;27723&quot;,&quot;DISCOUNT&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;ETF&quot;:&quot;N\/A&quot;,&quot;ETD&quot;:&quot;N\/A&quot;},{&quot;SERVICE&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;FREIGHT_CHARGE&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;TOT_CHARGE&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;PRICE&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;DISCOUNT&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;ETF&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;ETD&quot;:&quot;0&quot;}]}}</return>
        </ns1:getRatesResponse>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I have a json inside an xml response. however how do i retrieve it from the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [DOM classes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) to get the relevant text content. This will handle the entities. Then you can simply use [`json_decode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

For example ([demo](https://3v4l.org/e559L)):

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

$xml = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:getRatesResponse xmlns:ns1="urn:rpxwsdl">
            <return xsi:type="xsd:string">{&quot;RPX&quot;:{&quot;TITLE&quot;:&quot;Rates From Jakarta (JAK) TO Denpasar (DPS), Weight 1 Kg&quot;,&quot;DATA&quot;:[{&quot;SERVICE&quot;:&quot;PAS Reguler (PSR)&quot;,&quot;FREIGHT_CHARGE&quot;:&quot;27723&quot;,&quot;TOT_CHARGE&quot;:&quot;27723&quot;,&quot;PRICE&quot;:&quot;27723&quot;,&quot;DISCOUNT&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;ETF&quot;:&quot;N\/A&quot;,&quot;ETD&quot;:&quot;N\/A&quot;},{&quot;SERVICE&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;FREIGHT_CHARGE&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;TOT_CHARGE&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;PRICE&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;DISCOUNT&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;ETF&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;ETD&quot;:&quot;0&quot;}]}}</return>
        </ns1:getRatesResponse>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
XML;

$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'ISO-8859-1');
$doc->loadXML($xml);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$xpath->registerNamespace('ns1', 'urn:rpxwsdl');

$item = $xpath->query('/SOAP-ENV:Envelope/SOAP-ENV:Body/ns1:getRatesResponse/return');

if ($item->length > 0) {
    print_r(
        json_decode($item->item(0)->textContent, true, 512, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR)
    );
}
```